# How do I grab the value from an html form input box as its being entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I grab the value from an input box as its being entered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

onkeyup will be triggered every time a key is released. While it looks to be the solution it has some problems.

If the user move the cursor with the arrows, it is triggered and you have to check yourself if the field value didn't change.

If the user copy/paste a value in the input field with the mouse, or click undo/redo in the browser, `onkeyup` is not triggered.

Like in a mac or in google docs, I didn't want a save button to submit forms in our app, here is how I do it.
Any comment, or shortcut is welcome as it is a bit heavy.

1. **onfocus**, store the current value of the field, and start an interval to check for changes
2. when the user moves something in the input, there is a comparison with the old value, if different a save is triggered
3. **onblur**, when the user moves away from the field, clear the interval and event handlers

Here is the function I use, elm is the input field reference and after is a callback function called when the value is changed:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>so</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" onfocus="changeField(this, fldChanged);">
    <script>
        function changeField(elm, after){
            var old, to, val,
                chk = function(){
                    val = elm.value;
                    if(!old && val === elm.defaultValue){
                        old = val;
                    }else if(old !== val){
                        old = val;
                        after(elm);
                    }
                };
            chk();
            to = setInterval(chk, 400);
            elm.onblur = function(){
                to && clearInterval(to);
                elm.onblur = null;
            };
        };
        function fldChanged(elm){
            console.log('changed to:' + elm.value);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

use an onchange event handler for the input box.

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_onChange.html

Comment: I don't think onchange will fire when the text is being entered.

Comment: I didn't answer the OP's questions (probably because it was late.)  The other methods provided are better solutions as the onchange event does not fire during input, but onblur.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you used the "jquery" tag.  For jQuery, you can use the [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) method.

From the API documentation:

> ***Description***: Bind an event handler to the "keypress" JavaScript
>   event, or trigger that event on an
>   element.

The event will fire every time keyboard input is registered by the browser.

`.keydown()` and `.keyup()` are also available.  Their behavior is slightly different from `.keypress()` and is outlined by the API documentation as well.

The nice thing about jQuery is that you can use the same code across Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera and Chrome.