# Is there a way to capture x-browser paste events in mootools?

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, mootools, paste, mootools-events

I want to capture when a user pastes data into a text input field using mootools event system.

Anyone have experience of this?

Comment: I don't know mootools, but there is a `onpaste` event in all modern browsers.

Comment: Here's an answer to a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function will get fired whenever the keys 'ctrl+v' are pressed.

Mootools docs : http://www.mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Keyboard

**EDIT** : HTML and JS Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='core.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='more.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function keyPressed(e)
        {
            var evt = Event(e);
            evt.stop();
        }

        window.addEvent('domready', function()
        {
            var myKeyboardEvents = new Keyboard(
            {
                eventType: 'keyup', 
                events: 
                { 
                    'ctrl+v': keyPressed
                }
            });

            myKeyboardEvents.activate()

        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id='myForm'>
            <input type='text' name='some' id='username' value='stack@over.com'/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't forget you an copy/paste using ctrl+ins / shift+ins and the context menu - whereas you can trap keyboard events, a right-click / paste will work, not sure about onpaste

Comment: tried $('a').addEvent('paste',function(evt){...} and a keyUp Event with a check inside if( evt.key=='v' && evt.control) but neither work at the minute

Answer (score 1):

The `paste` event has become better supported in recent times: IE has had it since around 2000 (IE 5.5, I think), Firefox since 3.0, WebKit for a couple of years (not sure exactly when). You should use it where possible and fall back to detecting ctrl-v or shift-ins in other cases, or polling the input box's value using a timer.